# RubyPython ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, ruby

I'm having some trouble using the RubyPython gem from square one:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'rubypython'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> RubyPython.start
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

I suspect the problem is that RP is not looking for the right version of python. Am I on the right track here? If so, how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Seems like the path is not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a path problem. Try to specify the interpreter path explicitly:

```
RubyPython.start python_exe: `which python`.chomp
```